# Catkin_make error

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm having a problem with catkin_make. When I run run it i get

```
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
-- tum_ardrone: 1 messages, 5 services
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at rosberry_pichopter/CMakeLists.txt:94 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    src/rosberry_pichopter/joy/src/servo.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


-- Build files have been written to: /home/donni/catkin_ws/build
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

With a bunch of stuff before it. I don't know why I'm getting the error, becouse servo.cpp is in catkin_ws/src/rosberry_pichopter/joy/src/servo.cpp.
I'm using hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192824/catkin_make-error/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error:

```
CMake Error at rosberry_pichopter/CMakeLists.txt:94 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:
```

Means that cmake is looking for the file and did not find it. It looks for the file relatively to the base directory of your package (not the base directory of your catkin workspace!!!!). I. e. the error message is fully consistent with what you mentioned:

Your source file is placed in

```
catkin_ws/src/rosberry_pichopter/joy/src/servo.cpp
```

CMake looks for the file in

```
catkin_ws/src/rosberry_pichopter/src/rosberry_pichopter/joy/src/servo.cpp
```

The reason, I guess, is that you a have an `add_executable` or `add_library` in your CMakeLists.txt which looks like:

```
add_executable( your_target src/rosberry_pichopter/joy/src/servo.cpp )
```

while it should rather look like:

```
add_executable( your_target joy/src/servo.cpp )
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1